# How can I GET the Microsoft Profile Picture through the Graph API in C Sharp

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to implement Microsoft Profile Pictures with the Graph API in C# to create a UWP App and show these Pics through a HoloLens in Unity.

I found out that you need to use a HTTP Request but I can't get it working in C#.

I'm using the GraphTutorial from Getting Startet with GraphAPI [Click here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start)

And I'm starting with a blank page because I don't have any clue how I can get this to work in C#

The GraphExplorer shows me a Picture.

Hope you can help me out!

Greetings

```
public static async Task<Stream> GetUserPhoto(this GraphServiceClient graph, string userid)
    {
        try
        {
            return await graph
                .Users[userid]
                .Photo
                .Content
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
        }





        return null;
    }


    private class Bild
    { 

    private async Task LoadImageAsync(Person person)
    {
      await GetUserPhoto(APPID, EMAIL); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to access the picture using the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) ? Or are you having trouble making the API call in C# ? Are you using [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/) or HttpClient ? Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: You have to show your code.

Comment: edit :-) 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://github.com/dbarros/WindowsAPICodePack

Maybe try interfacing it with a `ShellFile`.

```
ShellFile sf = new ShellFile.FromFilePath(PathToFileHere);
BitMap ShellThumb = sf.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
```